# Which marketing-related classification challenges is a feed forward neural network suited to solve?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, feedforward-neural-networks

I am trying to think of some marketing-related classification challenges that a feed-forward neural network would be suited for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Has a data set been chosen? There's a wide variety of data out there (see [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets), [this](https://gengo.ai/datasets/the-50-best-free-datasets-for-machine-learning/), or [this](https://www.forbes.com/sites/bernardmarr/2018/02/26/big-data-and-ai-30-amazing-and-free-public-data-sources-for-2018/)).  Analytical possibilities are largely determined by the available data, so choosing your data would probably help to clarify your objectives.